# understanding weird output of printf function

Tags: c, printf

According to me

```
int a=0;
printf("%d",a);
```

works same as

```
char *ptr="%d"
```

ptr points to % and then ptr reads the whole string from % and 4 bytes  are read from memory.

Now consider the below code

```
printf("%d"+1,a);  //value of a=0
```

is same as

```
char *ptr="%d"
ptr+=1;
```

ptr now points to d and so string from d is printed

Now

```
printf(1+"Alex"); //prints lex
```

ptr points l and prints string from there on....

Now what will happen in the following cases?It appears to be out of my scope.

1. `printf("%",a);`
2. `printf("%%%%");`
3. `printf("%%d",a);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf("%",a);` does not have a valid conversion specifier, so it is covered by:

§7.21.6.1

> 9 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined. If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

`printf("%%%%");` will simply print `%%`, since `%%` is a conversion specifier. See the [`printf` man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

> %
>
> A '%' is written. No argument is converted. The complete conversion
>   specification is '%%'.

As mentioned in the comments, `printf("%%d",a);` is probably not undefined behavior. `%%` becomes `%` and the `a` is ignored.

§7.21.6.1

> 2 The fprintf function writes output to the stream pointed to by stream,
>   under control of the string pointed to by format that specifies how
>   subsequent arguments are converted for output. If there are
>   insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined. If
>   the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments
>   are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored. The fprintf
>   function returns when the end of the format string is encountered.

Comment: wHat i feel for printf("%%%%"); 
compiler notices 1st % it went past it.....then it noticed 2nd % instead of format specifier so it printed it......now it went to 3rd % and after it went past it to notice whether there is any format specifier but it didn't notice it..... so 4th % was printed....Am i rit?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this quote from the C Standard will help you

> 8 The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> % A % character is written. No argument is converted. The complete
> conversion specification shall be %%.

For example

```
printf("%%%%");
```

will output

```
%%
```